# how load data from Json to Json in Extjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, extjs

in my case, i want, if click the button "drilldown" chart load new data from another Json. This is my Store

```
Ext.define('DWP3.store.konten.Coba', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.coba',
 storeId: 'coba',
uses: [
    'Ext.data.Store'
],


        fields: [
           {name: 'periode'},
           {name: 'Teknik'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'resources/data/load2.php',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'view_sum1'
            }
        },
         autoLoad: true,
    });
 }
```

i want load the new data also from json which converted from mySQL. i want load this one :

```
newData : function(){
  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
           {name: 'periode'},
           {name: 'prodi'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'resources/data/load3.php', //from another load in php
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'view_sum2' // another root
            }
        },
         autoLoad: true,
   });
      return store;
}
```

i call the function like this in my chart.js:

```
       {
         text:'Test',
         handler:function(){
         this.down('cartesian').getStore().newData();
            }
        }
```

in this case i want if click the button my store load new data but from another Json which converted from mySQL. it is possible to do that?or do you have any solution from my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to declare your 2nd store the same way you did with the first one. And simply load it inside the handler of your drilldown :

```
handler : function() {
    Ext.getStore('your new store ID').load();
}
```

But I'm not really sure what you really want, your question isn't clear to me.